# Spurious Compilation Problems in VB6

Tags: compiler-construction, vb6, windows-xp

I've been compiling a VB6 application recently and have had a number of annoying problems with the resulting exe. When running it from the command prompt, the compiled executables will attempt to report problems to Microsoft on my behalf, or occasionally report that "This program cannot be run in DOS mode."

While I can "fix" this problem by making pointless changes to the source code and recompiling, I wonder if there is any reason for this and what I can do about it.

I'm using VB6 (SP6) on XP.

Answer (score 0):

I think that [this link](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/134489) may be useful. You are trying to start a Windows program in an environment that is Windows unaware. It seems that this behaviour of the DOS box can be changed.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, @Dabblernl, but sadly (in the time-honoured way with documentation) it directs me to select a tab that doesn't exist. I'll just have to grin and bear it, I expect.